# NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Time at gherkin.deps.com.google.gson.Gson.<init> (Gson.java:232)

Tags: java, cucumber, gson

My Runner file is working fine when executed through testNG in eclipse , But getting the above exception when executed by mvn clean install .

recently have updated Java 11 from Java 8 . Same was working in Java 8 but not in 11

Appreciate the Help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your cucumber version to latest 6xx or 7xx.